# Почему не работает import "github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.1-core/gl"

Tags: golang, opengl, импорт

Всё корректно установилось в GOPATH, однако при импорте VScode ругается и выдаёт две ошибки.

could not import github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.1-core/gl (no required module provides package "github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.1-core/gl")

error while importing github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.1-core/gl: build constraints exclude all Go files in D:\GoEnv\pkg\mod\github.com\go-gl\gl@v0.0.0-20211210172815-726fda9656d6\v4.1-core\gl

Вот так выглядит код в go.mod

```
module openGL

go 1.21.1

require (
    github.com/go-gl/gl v0.0.0-20211210172815-726fda9656d6 // indirect
    github.com/go-gl/glfw v0.0.0-20221017161538-93cebf72946b // indirect
)
```

Это код из go.sum

```
github.com/go-gl/gl v0.0.0-20211210172815-726fda9656d6 h1:zDw5v7qm4yH7N8C8uWd+8Ii9rROdgWxQuGoJ9WDXxfk=
github.com/go-gl/gl v0.0.0-20211210172815-726fda9656d6/go.mod h1:9YTyiznxEY1fVinfM7RvRcjRHbw2xLBJ3AAGIT0I4Nw=
github.com/go-gl/glfw v0.0.0-20221017161538-93cebf72946b h1:2hdUMUOJuLQkhaPAwoyOeSzoaBydYEkXkBEuqDuDBfg=
github.com/go-gl/glfw v0.0.0-20221017161538-93cebf72946b/go.mod h1:wyvWpaEu9B/VQiV1jsPs7Mha9I7yto/HqIBw197ZAzk=
```

Вот, что находится по нужному пути: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `go-gl` при сборке генерирует кучу кода на Си, поэтому недостаточно просто скачать исходники на Go. Для начала соберите ваш проект командой `go build .` Правда, я собирал код на линуксе, а не в Windows. Что нужно для сборки в Windows - я не знаю.

Comment: @PakUula При попытке собрать проект через go build кидает ту же ошибку "main.go:3:8: no required module provides package github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.1/glfw; to add it:
        go get github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.1/glfw", а при прописывании соответствующей команды всё устанавливается, однако при повторной попытке сборки кидает это: "imports github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.1/glfw: build constraints exclude all Go files in D:\GoEnv\pkg\mod\github.com\go-gl\glfw@v0.0.0-20221017161538-93cebf72946b\v3.1\glfw"

Comment: Распишите подробнее что и как вы компилируете. Я попробовал у себя маленький пример - собралось и запустилось.

Comment: @PakUula я компилирую через дефолтное разрешение Visual Studio Code, а сам язык скачивал с оф сайта 1.20.1 версию для windows'a чипов intel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я всегда компилирую в командной строке, явным образом вызывая `go build` или `go run`

Особенность вашего проекта заключается в том, что в процессе сборки `go build` генерирует код на С и компилирует его в объектные файлы для целевой платформы. В линуксах это делается легко и непринуждённо, а в Windows требует некоторых трюков. Я подозреваю, ваши проблемы проистекают именно из-за проблем интеграции с компилятором Си.

Итак, как я настроил среду для сборки `cgo` приложений в Windows.

1. `cgo` нужен компилятор с именем `gcc` и приложение `pkg-config`, которое находит необходимые библиотеки и генерирует опции для `gcc`, чтобы с этими библиотеками слинковаться.
2. `gcc` и `pkg-config` (и все необходимые утилиты, такие как `binutils`) для Windows обычно берут из тулчейна MinGW. Самый простой способ установить MinGW - установить через среду управления пакетами [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/)
3. Установите MSYS2, путь инсталляции должен быть только из латинских символов  и цифр, без пробелов. Например, `C:/msys64`.
4. Запустите терминал `msys` (путь к приложению `C:/msys64/msys2.exe`). Откроется окошко с шеллом `bash`. Выполните в этом шелле команду:

```
pacman -S  mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-pkg-config
```

5. Должна появиться папка `C:/msys64/mingw64/` с подпапками `bin`, `etc`, `include`, `lib`, `share`, `x86_64-w64-mingw32`. Добавьте `C:/msys64/mingw64/bin` в переменную `PATH`.
6. После того как всё настроите, перезапустите VS Code, чтобы приложение узнало о новом значении `PATH`

Для проверки соберите тестовое приложение https://github.com/go-gl/example в консоли PowerShell:

```
git clone https://github.com/go-gl/example
cd .\example\
go build ./gl41core-cube
```

Эти команды скачают из github тестовое приложение вращающегося кубика и соберут приложение для `go-gl v4.1`

```
go: downloading github.com/go-gl/gl v0.0.0-20210426225639-a3bfa832c8aa
go: downloading github.com/go-gl/mathgl v1.0.0
go: downloading github.com/go-gl/glfw/v3.3/glfw v0.0.0-20210410170116-ea3d685f79fb
go: downloading golang.org/x/image v0.0.0-20210220032944-ac19c3e999fb
(минут 5 на сборку)
```

Запуск приложения

```
.\gl41core-cube.exe
```

[image: gl41core-cube.exe]

Проверьте у себя - работает?

Comment: Не работает, таже ошибка и под папка x86_64-w64-mingw32 не создалась, а ещё папки там полностью пустые, в переменную Path я добавил C:\msys64\mingw64\bin.

Comment: Я не уверен, но возможно я разобрался, я добавил переменную CGO_ENABLED = 1, и теперь выскакивает другая ошибка, C compiler "gcc" not found: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%, сейчас попробую решить

Comment: Всёёёё работает УРААААААА!!! Я установил системную переменную CGO_ENABLED = 1, установил gcc и всё заработало, спасибо вам за помощь!

Comment: @NemoStreams поздравляю :) насчёт пустой папки `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` - наверное, я вам неправильный пакет mingw написал, сорри. В `msys` их несколько.